# assigning by reference into loaded package datasets

Tags: r, data.table

I am in the process of creating a package that uses a `data.table` as a dataset and has a couple of functions which assign by reference using `:=`.

I have built a simple package to demonstrate my `problem`

```
 library(devtools)
 install_github('foo','mnel')
```

It contains two functions

```
foo <- function(x){
  x[, a := 1]
}
fooCall <- function(x){
  eval(substitute(x[, a :=1]),parent.frame(1))
}
```

and a dataset (not lazy loaded) `DT`, created using

```
DT <- data.table(b = 1:5)
save(DT, file = 'data/DT.rda')
```

When I install this package, my understanding is that `foo(DT)` should assign by reference within `DT`.

```
 library(foo)
 data(DT)
 foo(DT)
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1

# However this has not assigned by reference within `DT`

DT
   b
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
```

If I use the more `correct`

```
tracmem(DT)
DT <- foo(DT)
# This works without copying
DT 
 b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1
untracemem(DT)
```

If I use `eval` and `substitute` within the function

```
fooCall(DT)
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1
# it does assign by reference 
DT
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1
```

Should I stick with

1. `DT <- foo(DT)` or the `eval`/`substitute` route, or
2. Is there something I'm not understanding about how `data` loads datasets, even when not lazy?

Comment: Never tried to update by reference data in packages! But isn't data in packages supposed to be read only given they're _sealed_? Typing `DT` at the end here doesn't mean it's been assigned by reference does it? DT could have been copied to `.GlobalEnv` and that could be where it has been updated.

Comment: Btw `tracemem` reports _duplications_ by R itself. It is unlikely to catch a copy that data.table does, for example when over-allocating for the first time because technically that's not a perfect duplication, but an over-allocation (albeit a shallow copy not a deep one).

Comment: Maybe try `alloc.col` on the data object in the package, and see what happens.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I thought data(DT) created a copy in the global environment, lazy loading might imply a locked dataset. I am not trying to update the copy in the package, but use the dataset in an example / vignette.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `data()` but yes that doesn't sound wrong. But R is creating it (not data.table) i.e. that's R's `data()` command which doesn't know about over-allocation. Similar to when you `load()` a data.table it won't be over-allocated until the first `:=` adds a new column. Does `library(foo); data(DT); alloc.col(DT); foo(DT)` work? Then we can go from there.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, as noted below `library(foo); data(DT); alloc.col(DT); foo(DT)` does work as required.

Comment: 8 years have passed and I am still running into this issue. Hence, I would like to ask if there is now a more proper way to handle this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with datasets or locking -- you can reproduce it simply using

```
DT<-unserialize(serialize(data.table(b = 1:5),NULL))
foo(DT)
DT
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that `data.table` has to re-create the extptr inside the object on the first access on `DT`, but it's doing so on a copy so there is no way it can share the modification with the original in the global environment.

---

[From Matthew] Exactly.

```
DT<-unserialize(serialize(data.table(b = 1:3),NULL))
DT
   b
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
DT[,newcol:=42]
DT                 # Ok. DT rebound to new shallow copy (when direct)
   b newcol
1: 1     42
2: 2     42
3: 3     42

DT<-unserialize(serialize(data.table(b = 1:3),NULL))
foo(DT)
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
DT                 # but not ok when via function foo()
   b
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```

```
DT<-unserialize(serialize(data.table(b = 1:3),NULL))
alloc.col(DT)      # alloc.col needed first
   b
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
foo(DT)
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
DT                 # now it's ok
   b a
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
```

Or, don't pass `DT` into the function, just refer to it directly. Use `data.table` like a database: a few fixed name tables in `.GlobalEnv`.

```
DT <- unserialize(serialize(data.table(b = 1:5),NULL))
foo <- function() {
   DT[, newcol := 7]
}
foo()
   b newcol
1: 1      7
2: 2      7
3: 3      7
4: 4      7
5: 5      7
DT              # Unserialized data.table now over-allocated and updated ok.
   b newcol
1: 1      7
2: 2      7
3: 3      7
4: 4      7
5: 5      7
```

Comment: @Matthew: but note that `alloc.col()` will equally *not* work inside functions (for the same reasons above) - you really need something that does not try to fake out references - e.g. what works is `DT <- DT[TRUE]`. This is something worth mentioning in `data.table` docs, because unserializing `data.table` objects creates an issue that is hard to trace (and it happens all the time - in workspaces, packages etc.).

Comment: Only an issue, I believe, if a column is needed to be added by reference to an unserialized data.table, from within a function, and that table name isn't known in advance (i.e. needs to be passed in via the function argument). I can't think of an example where calling `alloc.col(DT)` straight after the unserialize wouldn't be possible, but needed in practice as well. I tend to use data.table like a database; i.e. a few large fixed name tables in .GlobalEnv. Please see new edit.

Comment: @MatthewDowle (and Simon) -- thanks for the pointers, I can see that your second example is somewhat similar to my idea of constructing the appropriate call, and evaluating it in the correct parent environment. (`fooCall` in my question)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use `inst/extdata` to save the `rda` file (which would contain any number of data.table objects) and have a file `DT.r` within the `data` subdirectory

```
# get the environment from the call to `data()`
env <- get('envir', parent.frame(1))
# load the data
load(system.file('extdata','DT.rda', package= 'foo'), envir = env)
# overallocate (evaluating in correct environment)
if(require(data.table)){
# the contents of `DT.rda` are known, so write out in full
  evalq(alloc.col(DT), envir = env)

}
# clean up so `env` object not present in env environment after calling `data(DT)`
rm(list = c('env'), envir = env)



}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting. I wonder if `alloc.col` should be enhanced to accept a character vector as well? Then it could wrap the `load()` call. I don't think you need the `data.table::` prefix as `alloc.col` is exported and intended for user use.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, good point re `data.table::` fixed, and revised to specific case where results of `load` are known in advance. `alloc.col` might require an environment argument as well.

Comment: Good idea. [FR#2595](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2595&group_id=240&atid=978) to enhance `alloc.col` now filed.