# `:=' does not work when used from a function on a data.table loaded from disk

Tags: r, data.table

The `:=` does not seem to work when called from a function on a data.table which has just been loaded from disk. Doing something with the `data.table` first does help. Is this a bug in `data.table`, or am I missing something (i.e. abusing data.table and `:=`)?

Sample code:

```
# Generate a dummy data.table and save to disk
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=c(1:10), b=c(1:10))
save(DT, file="c:/temp/DT.rData")

# Now define and use a function which is supposed to change the data.table
> library(data.table)
> 
> myfn <- function(data="DT") {
+ DD <- get(x=data, inherits=TRUE, mode="list")
+ DD[, c:="a", verbose=TRUE] }
> load(file="c:/temp/DT.rData")
> myfn(data="DT")
.internal.selfref ptr is NULL. This is expected and normal for a data.table loaded from disk. If not, please report to datatable-help.
Growing vector of column pointers from truelength  0  to  102 . A shallow copy has been taken, see ?alloc.col. Only a potential issue if two variables point to the same data (we can't yet detect that well) and if not you can safely ignore this. To avoid this message you could alloc.col() first, deep copy first using copy(), wrap with suppressWarnings() or increase the 'datatable.alloccol' option.
.internal.selfref ptr is NULL. This is expected and normal for a data.table loaded from disk. If not, please report to datatable-help.
Detected that j uses these columns: <none> 
Assigning to all 10 rows
     a  b c
 1:  1  1 a
 2:  2  2 a
 3:  3  3 a
 4:  4  4 a
 5:  5  5 a
 6:  6  6 a
 7:  7  7 a
 8:  8  8 a
 9:  9  9 a
10: 10 10 a
# This seems to be the correct (desired) result, but does not "stick":
> DT
     a  b
 1:  1  1
 2:  2  2
 3:  3  3
 4:  4  4
 5:  5  5
 6:  6  6
 7:  7  7
 8:  8  8
 9:  9  9
10: 10 10
```

Running the same code with an extra line `DT <- copy(DT)` does change the DT as intended:

```
> myfn <- function(data="DT") {
+ DD <- get(x=data, inherits=TRUE, mode="list")
+ DD[, c:="a"] }
> 
> load(file="c:/temp/DT.rData")
> DT <- copy(DT)
> myfn(data="DT")
     a  b c
 1:  1  1 a
 2:  2  2 a
 3:  3  3 a
 4:  4  4 a
 5:  5  5 a
 6:  6  6 a
 7:  7  7 a
 8:  8  8 a
 9:  9  9 a
10: 10 10 a
> DT
     a  b c
 1:  1  1 a
 2:  2  2 a
 3:  3  3 a
 4:  4  4 a
 5:  5  5 a
 6:  6  6 a
 7:  7  7 a
 8:  8  8 a
 9:  9  9 a
10: 10 10 a
```

Is there some fundamental problem in the way I am using `:=` above? I tried an alternative definition of `myfn()`, using `set()` but the result was the same. Thanks.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.9
```

Comment: Removed. Apologies if I caused somebody pain, that was not my intention. I guess I assumed everybody would run the code in a clean session anyway.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195220/assigning-by-reference-into-loaded-package-datasets

Comment: Thank you both. The suggestion to use `aloc.col(DT)` before calling `myfn()` does do the job, as suggested in both the linked question and the answer which disappeared before I accepted it. 
Also, as suggested in the linked question, using `DT <- myfn(data="DT")` also works, and does not seem to need an `alloc.col()`.

Comment: Peter, even though the answer was possibly an option, I got the explanation totally wrong as it has nothing to do with `truelength` apparently (as shown from mnel's link). Hence the delete.