# data.table doesn't modify by reference if the object is freshly loaded from file?

Tags: r, data.table

It seems that if a `data.table` is freshly loaded, a function containing `:=` wouldn't modify by reference.

Can anyone reproduce it? Is it a bug?

```
test<-function(data){data[,ppp:=1]}

a<-data.table(x=1:2)
save(a,file="ttt")
load("ttt")
test(a) # show ppp
a # doesn't have ppp


b<-data.table(x=1:2)
test(b) # show ppp
b # has ppp
```

#### Update

It is kinda "feature" that if there is no slot left in the column pointer vector, a shallow copy will be performed. The `data.table` name is bound to the new vector. It works fine throughout the same scope. However, the outer scope cannot see this change unless manually bind the return value to a name.

```
options(datatable.alloccol=4)
options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)
a<-as.data.table(matrix(1:20, ncol=4))
truelength(a) # 4
test<-function(x){print(truelength(x));x[,pp:=1];print(truelength(x));x}
test(a)
a # doesn't change
```

Comment: If you turn on `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)`, you'll get some messages after `test(a)` that may be helpful.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195220/assigning-by-reference-into-loaded-package-datasets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A data.table needs to be over-allocated in memory for adding columns by reference to work. After loading it that's not the case:

```
load("ttt")
length(a)
#[1] 1
truelength(a)
#[1] 0

b <- data.table(x=1:2)
length(b)
#[1] 1
truelength(b)
#[1] 100
```

From `help(truelength)`:

> For tables loaded from disk however, truelength is 0 in R 2.14.0 and random in R <= 2.13.2; i.e., in both cases perhaps unexpected. data.table detects this state and over-allocates the loaded data.table when the next column addition or deletion occurs.

**But it seems like if you pass a (freshly loaded) data.table to a function and then add by reference inside the function over-allocation happens but doesn't reach the symbol up in the global environment (only the local symbol inside the function). If you do it in the global environment directly or don't pass the data.table as function parameter, it works.**

If the data.table is over-allocated already (as is normally the case, other than when freshly loaded from disk), then there are spare slots for the column to be added into by reference and no shallow copy (to achieve over-allocation) needs to be done by `:=` inside the function.

This might be worth a bug report (but I haven't checked if there is already one).

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] microbenchmark_1.3-0 data.table_1.8.8    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: The way to overallocate is to use `alloc.col`. See Simon's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208059/1385941

Comment: @mnel +1 Just to check are you saying that if freshly loaded datasets are to be added to by reference, then it's advisable to call `alloc.col` on them straight after loading?  I think I agree with that.  The other thing we could advise maybe is to pass data.tables by name to functions not by symbol then use `get` inside the function; e.g.  f=function(DTname){ get(DTname)[,newcol:=1] }  would be called by f("DT").