# data.table update join within a function causing deep copy

Tags: r, join, data.table, pass-by-reference

I have a function to update a column in a data.table passed by reference.
Sometimes this updates the table by reference, adding/updating a new column and sometimes creates a new copy of the table leaving the passed table unchanged.

In my reprex below, it behaves as I want, with the update made to the table passed as a parameter:

```r
require(data.table)
#> Loading required package: data.table
X <- data.table(ID=1:10000, ref=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), val = runif(10000))
Y <- data.table(ref=c('A','B','C','D'), v = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
ff <- function(a, b){
  print(address(a))
  a[b, on=.(ref), newval := val * v]
  print(address(a))
  invisible()
}
ff(X,Y)
#> [1] "000000001802a368"
#> [1] "000000001802a368"
address(X)
#> [1] "000000001802a368"
print(X)
#>           ID ref       val    newval
#>     1:     1   A 0.4559454 0.4559454
#>     2:     2   B 0.8987196 1.7974391
#>     3:     3   C 0.9053666 2.7160998
#>     4:     4   D 0.5118767 2.0475068
#>     5:     5   A 0.4649499 0.4649499
#>    ---                              
#>  9996:  9996   D 0.8669617 3.4678468
#>  9997:  9997   A 0.9251175 0.9251175
#>  9998:  9998   B 0.6165639 1.2331279
#>  9999:  9999   C 0.1048777 0.3146331
#> 10000: 10000   D 0.7430167 2.9720666
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

But in my 'real life' case a new copy is made and the passed table is unchanged.
This is the code

```r
str(X)
str(Y)
ff <- function(p_data,
                               p_units){
  print(address(p_data))
  p_data[p_units, on = .(GEWEI = Unit), ('newval') := BRGEW * SIFactor]
  print(address(p_data))
  invisible()
}
ff(X, Y)
address(X)
str(X)
```

This is the outcome:

```r
str(X)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  30108 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ MATNR : chr  "10000018" "10000034" "10000036" "10000038" ...
 $ MATKL : chr  "5027" "5027" "5027" "5027" ...
 $ MEINS : chr  "EA" "EA" "EA" "EA" ...
 $ BRGEW : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GEWEI : chr  "KG" "KG" "KG" "KG" ...
 $ VOLUM : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VOLEH : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ RAUBE : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PRDHA : chr  "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" ...
 $ MAKTX : chr  "Silo Quarterly Rental" "Pastoral Leases" "Weighbridge Tolls" "Directors & Officers Liability" ...
 $ class : chr  "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" ...
 $ weight: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cmatch: chr  "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "MATNR"
> str(Y)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  22 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Unit     : chr  "CCM" "CD3" "CDM" "CM" ...
 $ SIFactor : num  1.00e-06 1.00e-03 1.00e-03 1.00e-02 1.00e-03 1.00e-01 2.54e-02 1.00 1.00e+03 1.00e-03 ...
 $ Dimension: chr  "VOLUME" "VOLUME" "VOLUME" "LENGTH" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "Unit"
> ff <- function(p_data,
+                                p_units){
+   print(address(p_data))
+   p_data[p_units, on = .(GEWEI = Unit), ('newval') := BRGEW * SIFactor]
+   print(address(p_data))
+   invisible()
+ }
> ff(X, Y)
[1] "0000016ed1a71e78"
[1] "0000016ef670bc20"
> address(X)
[1] "0000016ed1a71e78"
> str(X)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  30108 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ MATNR : chr  "10000018" "10000034" "10000036" "10000038" ...
 $ MATKL : chr  "5027" "5027" "5027" "5027" ...
 $ MEINS : chr  "EA" "EA" "EA" "EA" ...
 $ BRGEW : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GEWEI : chr  "KG" "KG" "KG" "KG" ...
 $ VOLUM : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VOLEH : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ RAUBE : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PRDHA : chr  "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" "700017000510000384" ...
 $ MAKTX : chr  "Silo Quarterly Rental" "Pastoral Leases" "Weighbridge Tolls" "Directors & Officers Liability" ...
 $ class : chr  "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" ...
 $ weight: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cmatch: chr  "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" "700017000510000384XX5027" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "MATNR"
```

The original table (passed by reference) is not updated.
What is the difference between these scenarios that causes one to be updated by reference and the other results in a copy?
My real X table is very large and I want to avoid repeatedly copying it when updating a single column.

Further finding.  If I make a copy of the original table, and pass this to the function then it is updated by reference.  But when I pass the original table it is not.

```r
> Y <- copy(X)
> all.equal(X,Y)
[1] TRUE
> xopt_f_DQ_convert3(X, 'BRGEW', 'GEWEI', 'newval')
> xopt_f_DQ_convert3(Y, 'BRGEW', 'GEWEI', 'newval')
> all.equal(X,Y)
[1] "Different number of columns" "Different column names"
```

The new calculated column has been added to Y, but not to X.

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of data that triggers this behaviour.  Is it possible that the join causes a different number of rows to be generated - which would require a deep copy.

Comment: The number of rows is unchanged (30108).
Stranger still... If I make a full copy of X (Z <- copy(X)), and pass Z to the function then it updates Z by reference, but when I pass X it makes the copy.

Comment: I agree this sounds intriguing.  But unless you can post a fully reproducible example, I expect it will be hard for anyone to diagnose.

Comment: Yeah, there is something amiss with the internals of X, I guess. Instead of constructing Z by a copy, maybe just `setDT(X)` in-place to try to fix it. This might be relevant re why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494284/data-table-doesnt-modify-by-reference-if-the-object-is-freshly-loaded-from-file The same happens if you have truelength 100 and add a 101st column in a function, I think.

Comment: Thanks @Frank.  That explains it and reflects the situation.  The base table for X was loaded from .RData, so apparently not enough space allocated for additional column(s).  In normal mode this shouldn't be a problem as the table is read in from a database, but in this case was the resumption of a RStudio session.  I guess, to be safe we should check the address before and after, but still not sure how to relay this back to the calling frame.

Comment: @dww, I appreciate that this is hard to diagnose without a reproducible example.  I may be able to get to that with Frank's insight, but a difficult one to reproduce.  Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: In these cases, you can preallocate enough columns with `alloc.col` beforehand. `:=` is internally smart enough to check if enough columns are available and otherwise allocates more. If you want to ensure that you always manipulate the "same object" you can also assign in the correct namespace similar to how its done [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/eed712ef45fd9198de6aa1ac1b672a7347253d18/R/data.table.R#L1167-L1214)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and insights.  To wrap this up I summarise the key points identified.

1. This can occur where the data.table has been loaded from a .RData as there is no over-allocation of column space in this case.
2. You can allocate additional column space using `alloc.col` after loading the table
3. If it is suitable in the context, pass the name of the table in the function parameter and use `get(name)` to reference in the table within the function.  This will ensure that any update is done in the original namespace.

Comment: Subsequent finding.  The operation `colnames(DT) <- columnNameVector` drops any overallocation of the data table.  After this `length(DT) == truelength(DT)`, so a good idea to `alloc.col` after such a column assignment.

Comment: Or preferably use `setnames()` to set/change column names by reference.