# Generating a new variable with get(data.table) directly after loading data.table object

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to generate a new variable in a data.table which I generated, saved and loaded again. After loading I adress the data.table indirectly through get() and this does not work for generating a new variable as long as I dont adress it directly for variable creation before.
Possibly it is some kind of environment issue?

```
# Generate data.table
t<-data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4))
tStr<-"t"
names(t)

# Generate Variable a -> ok
get(tStr)[, a:=1]
names(t)

# Generate Variable b -> ok
t[, b:=1]
names(t)

# Save
save(t, file="test.Robj")
load("test.Robj", .GlobalEnv)

# Generate Variable c -> fails 
get(tStr)[, c:=1] 
names(t)

# Generate Variable d -> ok
t[, d:=1]
names(t)

# Generate Variable e -> ok again !?
get(tStr)[, e:=1]
names(t)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: seems like a bug to me

Comment: [#479](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/479) is similar to this one. Not fixed yet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208059/1385941 for a related issue

Answer (score 4):

This is because important meta data does not survive the storage action:

```
> t<-data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4))
> attr(t, ".internal.selfref")
<pointer: 0x0000000000100788>
> save(t, file="test.Robj")
> load("test.Robj", .GlobalEnv)
> attr(t, ".internal.selfref")
<pointer: (nil)>
> t[, d:=1]
> attr(t, ".internal.selfref")
<pointer: 0x0000000000100788>
```

Notice how you lose the memory pointer.  I'm not sure this is so much a bug as an inherent conflict between what a `data.table` is and what `save` does.  It seems in order for this to work properly we would need a special `load` method that re-assigns the internal pointer on loading `data.table` objects.

In this case, using the modify by reference seems to reset the pointer.

**EDIT**: as a workaround in your use case, you can try:

```
t <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4))
save(t, file="test.Robj")
load("test.Robj", .GlobalEnv)
assign("t", get("t")[, c:=3])
t
```

which works as expected:

```
   x c
1: 1 3
2: 2 3
3: 3 3
4: 4 3
```

Also note that expecting:

```
get("t")[, c:=3]
```

will work is a little bit like expecting that:

```
get("x") <- 5
```

will work.  `data.table` might in the future add this feature, but it you're treading in this murky area where the reference nature of `data.table` really starts conflicting with the R semantics.

Comment: It's true that the external pointer is lost. But that's only part of the reason. If you do: `t[, c := 1]` immediately after loading, it'd work, because it detects that the self reference is invalid and corrects it (=> shallow copy + over-allocation), adds the new column and then *assigns the new object back to the parent environment* (`t` is a *symbol*). But with `get(.)[, c := 1]`, it's slightly harder to *assign back to the parent environent*. This has not yet been done (at least for this use case).

Comment: @Arun, seems like it will be challenge to come up with something that works in every case.  I think at some point you end up working around the R no-references semantics (e.g. `colnames<-`, etc.) and provide work-arounds for those cases (e.g. `setnames`).

Comment: ok, seems more complicated issue than i taught, thank you for the workaround BrodieG, it works for my purpose